# How to get selected date in this format "Sunday-Jan 15, 2016"?

Tags: java, android

If I am selecting date from calendar it should show in this "Sunday-Jan 15, 2016" format. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This can help you:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html

Comment: I am not sure try this. SimpleDateFormat("EEEE-mmm dd, yyyy")

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code(assuming u are getting the date object from calendar),Please note that month is 0 based(ie 0 indicates january)

```
        Calendar cal=new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.set(2016,2, 19);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE-MMM dd,YYYY");
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: I am selecting date from android date picker and getting separately int year, int month, int day

Answer (score 0):

You can use format "EEEE-MMM dd, yyyy". See below code.

```
 Date today = new Date();
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE-MMM dd, yyyy");
 System.out.println(dateFormat.format(today));
```